# Inject values in list property dynamically in spring

Tags: java, spring

In spring, I want to inject values in list property dynamically. Is it possible?

For e.g. Instead of specifying value 1 three times, does there exist some property which can repeat this values multiple times based on some value.

```
<bean id='myBean' class-"com.foo.Xyz">
 <property name="myList">
    <value>1</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>1</value>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Please let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: I guess this might be possible with SpEL, but it looks like a strange requirement

Comment: I think it would be a bad idea if you could. Sounds like you would be putting some of your application's logic into the Spring config - but it should only really be dealing with wiring the components of your application together.

Comment: Actually I have a class C which implements `Runnable`. It has its own dependencies So I am using spring to get fully constructed instance of this class. 
Now I want to schedule 'X' no of such threads in a thread pool(`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
`). Right now, I am using `appContext.getBean('c')` in for loop X times and scheduling it, but it requires access to app context which  I read that it's not a good practice.

Comment: So I was thinking, if I could get a list of such instances from spring itself. Could not think of any other approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about custom `FactoryBean`?

```
public class RepeatingListFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Object> {

    private final Object item;
    private final int count;

    public RepeatingListFactoryBean(Object item, int count) {
        this.item = item;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject() throws Exception
    {
        final ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(count);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            list.add(item);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return item.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can use it in the following way (however I haven't tested it):

```
<bean id="listFactory" class="RepeatingListFactoryBean">
  <constructor-arg value="1"/>  <!-- item -->
  <constructor-arg value="3"/>  <!-- count -->
</bean>

<bean id="myBean" class-"com.foo.Xyz">
  <property name="myList" ref="listFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Note that both count and an object that is to be repeated are declaratively configurable.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, but wouldn't adding same `item` multiple times in list refer to same instance? I want different instances of item class in this list.

Comment: You mentioned you know how `getBean()` works - just inject `BeanFactory` to `RepeatingListFactoryBean` and pass `beanName` rather than concrete bean to the constructor. Finally - call `getBean()` on each iteration and you're done.

Comment: thanks. For that I have to make it implement `BeanFactoryAware` if I am right. but is it any better than implementing `ApplicationContextAware`?

Comment: Yes, use `BeanFactoryAware` - the smallest possible interface you require. This makes your code more robust and flexible.